# Firebase storage images using too much data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-gridview

Im developing an app to show images in a grid view using firebase with info about it.

I have noticed that its using lots data. I switched show current data incoming and outgoing on, to display in my notifications. It's using data even though images have loaded.

[data usage at 5:13 pm]

[data usage at 5:14 pm]

[data usage at 5:16 pm]

[data usage at 5:20 pm]

[Images have loaded and still using data...]

[The images in the storage and size]

[link to all images](https://ibb.co/album/gKU3BF)

I have an activity which reads my database, inside there i loop through the database, I then parse the data to an object class with gets and sets.

```
 found_animal animal = new found_animal(imgUrl
             ,animalBreed 
             ,animalCoat 
             ,animalColour 
             ,animalEarType 
             ,animalGender 
             ,animalIDTag, 
             animalSize, 
             animalTail, 
             animalType, 
             latitude, 
             longitude, 
             name, 
             number,Date);
```

I then have a class which extends this class using an Array Adapter

```
public class found_animal_array extends ArrayAdapter<found_animal>
```

I download the images using this code

```
    found_animal card = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.imgUrl= card.getImgUrl();
String ref = "myref" + viewHolder.imgUrl;
        storageRef.child(ref).getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

                final  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0,bytes.length);
            viewHolder.im.post(new Runnable() { //im is a imageview
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    viewHolder.im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }) ;


        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Log.i("something went wrong", exception.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

**Ive just rerun that activity and noticed when the scrollview on the gridview gets moved, it uses data.. Like it re-downloads the images.**

Comment: As you scroll, getView of adapter is called. If you put your download code in getitem or getview then it is run on each scroll.

Comment: So where about should i put the download code? It is currently in the getView. @BirendraSingh

Comment: You can save the image once downloaded. Then before downloading you can check if the image file exists on device. Download the image only if it does not exist on the device.

Answer (score -1):

Save the URL of the images in the database with some identifying logic, then load the images from the URLs using the Glide library. It will take care of the memory and caching the images.

Comment: why the downvote? I use this technique and it works fairly.